# unable to access form data when *ngIf = "true" is applyed to form

Tags: angular

I am trying to print form data in below template (`value1` and `value2`). `value1` is being printed as expected but value2 is empty.However if i remove `*ngIf = "true"` it  works fine.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfpced?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<form class = "input-form" #inputForm="ngForm" *ngIf="true">
  <input ngModel name="inputData" required>
  <i>value1:{{inputForm.value|json}}</i>
</form>
<i>value2:{{inputForm.value|json}}</i>
```

Comment: Simply declaring ```*ngIf="true"``` ..  What is the purpose of it??

Comment: What's the use of obvious condition `*ngIf="true"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working because the structural directive `*ngIf` creates a new template reference under the hood. This way the `inputForm` variable is no longer accessible, because those cannot be shared across templates. You need to use `@ViewChild` inside your component to access it.

Basically what the `ngIf` does is:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
  <form class = "input-form" #inputForm="ngForm">
    <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="inputData" required>
    <i>value1:{{inputValue|json}}</i>
  </form>
</ng-template>
<i>value2:{{inputForm.value|json}}</i>
```

As you can see the `inputForm` is now in its own template, and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Here you can see a working [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wys4av?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: so by removing ngIf, template variables will become available through out the template?

Comment: @BearNithi yes, from parent to child, not from sibling to sibling, or child to parent. I've added a stackblitz with a working example. Ah, but you are not the one who asked the question :D

Answer (score 0):

use *ngIf with `<i>` not with `<from>`

```
<form class = "input-form" #inputForm="ngForm" >
  <input ngModel name="inputData" required>
  <i>value1:{{inputForm.value|json}}</i>
</form>
<i *ngIf="true">value2:{{inputForm.value | json}}</i>
```

Or you can use like this

HTML:

```
<form class = "input-form" #inputForm="ngForm" *ngIf="true">
  <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" name="inputData" required>
  <i>value1:{{inputValue|json}}</i>
</form>
<i>value2:{{inputValue|json}}</i>
```

TypeScript:

```
inputValue: string;
```

you can declare value in ts and use double binding `[(ngModel)]="inputValue"`

> Can you elaborate ur problems so that we can understand better?

Comment: no, I want to have *ngIf on form only. What you are saying is simple but that's not what I want.